# Plotting a Specific Location on map view with latitude and longitude

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview

I want to plot a specific point on the map having the lat and lon from an api.

**Program flow**:

1. Get LAT & LON from api (done)
2. Ping api again via timer after every 5 seconds to get the latest location (done)
3. Plot location with retrieved LAT & LON on map

The issue is every code on the net has to do with 2 points, so user loc and destination loc. I cant seem to get it to work without user loc. I have however coded this to plot the location. However, with this when I touch the map, the map zooms out. Another issue is when I get another point the previous one also remains on the screen. (for testing purpose I hard coded the lat and lon but when I connect the api code that refreshes, prior points remain and the map code is the same as this. The lat and lon are passed via func parameters in  createAnnotation().)

**My code**:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView.delegate = self // or connect in storyboard
        createAnnotation()
    }

    func createAnnotation(){
        let annotations = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotations.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.87369, longitude: -87.813293)
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotations)
    }}
```

*How Do I plot the coordinates properly? and then delete the prior and show the new one?.*

Comment: We need to see what you have tried and where you are struggling. Have you had a look at this - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452409-removeannotation?language=swift%3F ?
You need a mechanism to 'remember' where the last annotation was and then remove it when you have a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the "previous one also remains on the screen" problem: don't keep making a new annotation and calling `addAnnotation` if you don't want to keep adding new annotations. Instead, keep hold of the annotation that you add, and move it later using its coordinate property. Something like this maybe:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    var annotationForThing: MKPointAnnotation?    
    var coordinateOfThing: CLLocationCoordinate2D? {
       didSet {
           guard let newCoord = coordinateOfThing else {
               if let existing = annotationForThing {
                   mapView.removeAnnotation(existing)
               }
               return
           }
           if let existing = annotationForThing {
                existing.coordinate = coordinateOfThing
           }
           else {
               let newAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
               newAnnotation = coordinateOfThing
               mapView.addAnnotation(newAnnotation)
               annotationForThing = newAnnotation
           }
       }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView.delegate = self // or connect in storyboard
    }
```